# How to set resolve for babel-loader presets

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to make a bundle with webpack. I have a bit complex dependency: some components require other ones that are located in some `/home/.../` folder.

Component (`/home/.../far-away-components/base-component.js` file):

```
import {base_component} from "base-component";
exports class MyComponent extends base_component {
   ...
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                loader: "babel",
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', "stage-0"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "base-component": "/home/.../far-away-components/base-component.js"
    }
};
```

The problem is that `far-away-components` folder doesn't contain `node_modules` and I get an error: `Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/home/.../far-away-components"`.

How can I set `resolve` for `babel-loader` presets?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Solution [from github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/166#issuecomment-160866946):

```
query: {
  presets: [
    'babel-preset-es2015',
    'babel-preset-react',
    'babel-preset-stage-0',
  ].map(require.resolve),
}
```

Comment: Looks cool. For personal interest: did you try a .babelrc file since this is the goto approach for babel use atm? And be careful: the order in which you call the presets matters.

Comment: Works great! Thanks @mqklin. For others just don't forget 'babel-preset-' prefix so that it could be resolved.

Comment: What magic is this? `map(require.resolve)` does exactly what I need it to do, but how? Can anyone link to some documentation on how this works?

Comment: @Astrotim `map` returns new array with every element invoked inside `require.resolve` function: equal to `query: { presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'), require.resolve('babel-preset-react'), require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-0')] }`

Comment: Thanks @mqklin. My confusion was in thinking `resolve` was Webpack's method, however I now know that in this context it is the Node global. It also helps to see it written in the longhand form `require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015')`

Comment: This really helped me

Answer (score 1):

@mqklin: You needed this work-around using, ".map(require.resolve)", because you did not exclude /node_modules/ in your loaders. The format below should work:

```
    loaders: [
  {
    test: [/\.js$/, /\.es6$/],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about run

```
npm init
```

in /home/.../far-away-components folder,
and then use npm to install what you need.

Comment: I don't want to do it, because I have all necessary `node_modules` near `webpack.config.js`. I need option like `resolve.fallback` but for `babel-loader` presets.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from [@mick-feller at this github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/149#issuecomment-365472735) worked nicely for me, telling webpack not to follow symlinks:

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false
    },
```

See also [webpack docs at `resolve.symlinks`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvesymlinks).

Comment: Webpack team advises against this in this blog post: https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/