# `.babelrc` file can't find presets in a nested node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have a directory structure like this:

```
> build
    > node_modules
    > webpack.config.js
> .babelrc
> .gitignore
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Currently I'm getting the following error...

`Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`

Are there any options within the `.babelrc` file that will allow me to specify the path to node_modules? Or any other way to fix this issue?

- Unfortunately there is no way to move the node_modules out to the root.

Comment: you have installed the preset? if not, use `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save` on console

Comment: yes installed everything it works if the node_modules folder is at the root level, but my issue is, that isn't an option, any ideas?

Comment: @Jai I'm in the same boat, have you found a solution?

Comment: @GaryChang afraid not :( in the end we had to change the folder structure. If you find a way around i'd love to hear about it!

Comment: @Jai, Yes I worked around it, for myself at least. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is currently no option in `.babelrc` to control the way Babel loads modules. But there are a few workarounds to solve the problem in various situations.

Babel actually accepts both strings and (module) objects as presets and plugins, so you can pass either the module's name (in which case Babel will try to resolve and load it using its own mechanism), or you can load the module yourself and pass it directly to Babel.

The problem is that if you use `.babelrc`, as it's JSON, you can obviously only pass the module's name, which subjects you to Babel's built-in module-loading mechanism.

If you use webpack, you can abandon `.babelrc` altogether and directly pass options to Babel in webpack config, like this:

```
query: {
  presets: [
    'babel-preset-es2015',
    'babel-preset-react',
    'babel-preset-stage-0',
  ].map(require.resolve),
}
```

See: [How to set resolve for babel-loader presets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574403/how-to-set-resolve-for-babel-loader-presets)

If you use Babel directly, in your own code, then you can still use `.babelrc`, but change the code that reads it, to load the presets and plugins yourself.

for example, if you have the following code to read `.babelrc`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var config = JSON.parse(babelrc);

require('babel-core/register')(config);
```

You can change it to something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var config = JSON.parse(babelrc);

config.presets = config.presets.map(function(preset) {
  return require.resolve('babel-preset-' + preset);
});
config.plugins = config.plugins.map(function(plugin) {
  return require.resolve('babel-plugin-' + plugin);
});

require('babel-core/register')(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `resolve` property in webpack.

`resolve` lets you set the source location for your modules:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['build/node_modules']
},
```

Comment: will this affect the source directories of the .babelrc file though?