# webpack use global babel-loader presets

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I want to use global modules/presets to use with webpack (i.e. don't want to install them in the project)

my config file : webpack.config.js

```
const config = {
entry: './src/js/app.js',
output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: '[name].js'
},
resolveLoader: {
    modules: [process.env.APPDATA + "\\npm\\node_modules", 'node_modules']

},
resolve: {
    modules: [process.env.APPDATA + "\\npm\\node_modules"]

},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                 'presets': ['babel-preset-es2015'].map(require.resolve)
                // 'presets': ['babel-preset-es2015']                  
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/

        }
    ]
}
}

module.exports = config;
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574403/how-to-set-resolve-for-babel-loader-presets/) but it didn't work for me.
I'm not much familiar with nodejs. I was succesfull in using loaders from global install using `resolveLoader:modules
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Think I have similar goal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697125/bundling-angularjs-with-webpack-using-global-node-modules

Comment: @AndreasBaaserud No, sorry. I gave up on using webpack that day. The webpack documentation was going over my head.