# Bundling AngularJS with Webpack, using global node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

What I want too archieve: Bundle angularjs application with webpack, but refer to node_modules folder located in a different location on the same filesystem.

---

- For this case, lets say my source code of the angular application is
  located in folder "/source/code".
- And for the external node modules,
  located in "/global/npm/App1/node_module"
- Application name: "App1"

---

What I have done so far:

1. Installed the angular application App1 with "npm install -g", so node modules will be located inside App1, in the global npm folder /global/npm/App1
2. Then I try to bundle App1 from /source/code. This won't work since I am missing node modules, which are located in /global/npm/App1/node_module.

How can I refer to the node modules located in /global/npm/App1/node_module?
Do I have to use absolut path for each module I require in webpack.config.js?

Comment: I'm sure your use case is perfectly valid, but it sounds like this could be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - importing global modules from your application is very, *very* rarely the right path to take. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to bundle the application with the global node modules.

Comment: Whats the use case for this?  Is quite an npm anti-pattern.

Comment: @roughcoder. Thing is, this angular application lies inside a project folder including an java application. Each time we build the java application, we remove old source code and fetch new source code from git. Which means node modules are not in the source code anymore since new code has taking their place. So I don't want to download node modules all over again every time we build the application.

Comment: I see, id try the `resolve-modules` section within webpack, additionally you might have better luck not importing them globally and just importing them into a folder outside of your project folder.   This might resolve some issues you may get with packages not playing well when installed globally.  Additionally you could add the folder to git and keep it versioned controlled as well.

Comment: If the size/speed of downloading dependencies is a concern, you might be well served by upgrading to NPM 5 (or switching to the Yarn client), which has better caching, or using an on-premises NPM proxy such as Artifactory or Nexus. Not a total solution to your problem, but it might help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature within Webpack you are looking for is the `resolve-modules`.  This allows you to add additional folders that can be used without the need to add a path into them, almost acting like they are within the `node_modules` folder.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules

For example

```
const globalNpm = path.join(__dirname, 'global', 'npm', 'App1', 'node_module'),

resolve: {
        modules: [
            globalNpm
        ]
    }
```

I find the using path.join make your webpack code more likely to work across platforms (windows, mac, etc).  The path in the above example may be wrong as I could really get your folder structure from your question.  But the above should allow you require modules directly from your global npm folder.

Please the the above feature is mostly intended for large project and files that could be moved, or reused elsewhere, it stops the need to have

```
const module = require('../../../a-folder/../../fancycomponent')
```

On a side note - installing NPM packages globally to be used just within one app is not a normal pattern and can lead to problems, especially with permissions and versioning on local and CI/CD pipelines.