# Using babel plugin in webpack configuration file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

In their website, webpack shows plugin usage like this

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'})
  ]
```

I want to use babel plugin transform-async-to-generator, so I added it in babelrc file but I dont know this is enough, should I add it also webpack file ? If so how

I can not be sure if writing plugin in webpack config file required because right now I am getting runtime error and not sure if it works writing only in babelrc file.

my current webpack config file

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'partner/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'partner_bundle.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Check for all js files
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [
            'babel-preset-env',
            'babel-preset-stage-0'
          ].map(require.resolve)
        },
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!other-module)/
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: { symlinks: false }
}
```

babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-async-generator-functions",
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": false,
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add a `module` entry to your webpack config to use the `babel-loader`. Your `.babelrc` files defines what babel should do. Including `babel-loader` in your webpack config actually runs babel on your code. [Check out this tutorial on using babel with webpack](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-data/babel-webpack/)

Comment: I added webpack config file in my post, already using babel loader, I am asking for babel polugins only, how can I add it in webpack config file, or should I do ?

Comment: `babel-loader` will automatically use the `.babelrc` file, so you don't have to add the same config in your `webpack.config.js`. Actually, you could also put the babel presets that you currently have in your webpack config into the `.babelrc`, too.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can see in my webpack config how I include the babel plugins:

```
    test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/, // JSX and JS files should be present.
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            // Babel must be required like this to be able to use npm-link to link to shared code, see:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574403/how-to-set-resolve-for-babel-loader-presets/
            presets: [
                [node_modules + '/@babel/preset-env', {
                    // Ref: 1) http://2ality.com/2017/02/babel-preset-env.html
                    // 2) http://caniuse.com/usage-table
                    // In case it supports the browserlist in package.json, remove this here, see:
                    // https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/149
                    "targets": {"browsers": ["> 4%", "safari 10", "ie 11", "iOS 9"]},
                    "modules": false,
                    "useBuiltIns": 'entry',
                    // "debug": true
                }],
                [node_modules + '/@babel/preset-react'],
            ],
            plugins: [
                node_modules + '/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                node_modules + '/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'].map(require.resolve)
        }
    }]
```